# Coldfusion/MAMP Pro/Windows 10

Tags: apache, coldfusion, mamp, coldfusion-11, mamp-pro

Documentation on setting up Mamp to work with Coldfusion in a Windows environment seems to be pretty limited, so here I am.

I have both MAMP PRO and COLDFUSION 11 set up on a WINDOWS 10 computer. Mamp is pointed to the correct Document Root folder and both Apache and MySQL services start correctly (I assume). When I navigate to 'localhost' in my browser, all I can see is the ColdFusion source - not a rendered page. I assume ColdFusion isn't running in this instance. The .htaccess file seems to be working as my site redirects are all functioning.

I assume I have my MAMP PRO config file set up incorrectly or I configured my ColdFusion web servers wrong. I can figure out where I need to point the web servers in OSX, but it seems to be a different setup in Windows.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

When you see the source of .cfm files, your web server (Apache) does not know about your ColdFusion server even if it's running.

Un-install CF11, keep Apache running while re-installing CF, CF install process should see your Apache and install the "connector".

***UPDATE:*** CF11 install needs the manual input of 'configuration directory' and 'server binary' values for Apache.

With the defaults install for MAMP PRO the configuration directory for Apache is `"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Appsolute\MAMPPRO\conf\"` and the server binary is `"C:\MAMP\bin\apache\bin\httpd.exe"`

The server root is at `"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Appsolute\MAMPPRO\mamp\"` where you can drop a test `'index.cfm'` file.

Comment: With the defaults install for MAMP PRO the configuration directory for Apache is "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Appsolute\MAMPPRO\conf\" and the server binary is "C:\MAMP\bin\apache\bin\httpd.exe"

Comment: Are you able to login into ColdFusion Administrator at http://localhost:8888/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm and finish the ColdFusion install?