# Localhost Coldfusion install showing cfquery parameters on page (Not speaking with ODBC)

Tags: coldfusion, odbc, mamp

**Goal:**
Run cfquery of remote server on local Coldfusion install.

**Problem/Symptoms:**
The cfquery parameters are printing onto the screen, instead of running query on remote.[Example of cfquery parameter printout on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiOiu.png)

[image: Example of cfquery parameter printout on screen]

**Facts:**

- Running Mac OS X Mojave (10.14.3).
- Coldfusion is installed. I can access the CF Admin panel at http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm
- Data Source is installed in Coldfusion Admin and status is "OK"
- Using Mamp Pro 5.3.  It's running -- can start and stop Apache.
- Apache is running on port 80
- Updated ODBC Actual SQL Server drivers (Version 4.2.0 from ActualTech).  Tested connection to server with driver and it is working.
- Remote database is using port 1433

I'm sure there are more questions to answer, but hopefully that's a decent start.  What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update: 3/17/2019**

Feeling stuck here.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled CF2018 and MAMP Pro.  I've used the wsconfig applet for Adobe Coldfusion (ACF) as [described by Brian Lang](https://brilang.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/installing-coldfusion-10-under-mamp-pro-2-on-os-x-lion/) and I've also tried the [manual approach as described by Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-apache-manual-connector-configuration.html).

---

**Update: 4/19/2019**

I may have figured this out, now that there is a release of Mac OS 10.14.4.  Going to test it on another computer to confirm that the process works and that I have all the steps documented, then will share answers.

Comment: 1. What is the file extension of the page that you are running? I suspect that it is htm or html. 2. Do you have any examples of `.cfm` pages that do anything ColdFusion ish? Try `<cfoutput>#now()#</cfoutput>` and see if it prints out the time.

Comment: 1) Agree with James. What type of file are you trying to run? .cfm? 2) Can you show the code that's giving you the incorrect display? Is that query inside `cfquery` tags? 3) OT Code Review: If you have a column named `Year_2018` that appears to be boolean, what do you do when it's 2019? This is a pretty big code smell indicating you might want to take another look at your database design.

Comment: Looks like a debug output. Something was copied from cfquery tags and left on the page

Comment: Thanks @JamesAMohler.  That page is a CFM file, but it feels like only the html, css and js are running.  There is a header menu that isn't pulling in, so that's probably a clue that Coldfusion isn't working on that install.

Running `<cfoutput>#now()#</cfoutput>` printed out `#now()#`.

Comment: @Shawn, you are correct.  1) Running a cfm page.  2) The code that is displaying is what is inside the cfquery tags. 3) The code works on the live site, so this is just a matter of my local install not speaking with coldfusion.

I'm not seeing any errors on screen, so not sure how to debug this.  I turned on debugging and logging settings in Admin, but the log wasn't helping me much: seemed unrelated.

Comment: Since it seems like the problem is related to Coldfusion not working on my local install, I'm going to follow the instructions on [this post comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44598981/570747) and see if that helps anything.  Perhaps the connector didn't see that Apache was running (in Mamp Pro) when it installed the first time?

Comment: It is a fairly common issue for the connector to Apache to fail.

Comment: I've re-installed Coldfusion 2018.  The wsconfig process didn't initiate during install, so I ran it separately to connect Apache -- but it's still now working.

Does CFIDE and Coldfusion need to be installed in the same directory as my local dev site? I've got Coldfusion 2018 installed in the Applications folder and my sites live in my Sites folder.  How do I get the local site to know that Coldfusion is running?

Comment: I've tried the manual connector instructions here: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-apache-manual-connector-configuration.html

No success.  Apache won't start after implementing this.

Any thoughts on whether uninstalling Coldfusion and MAMP Pro, and reinstalling them help?

Comment: Sounds like I'm not alone here:

[2016 MacOS 10.14 Mojave preinstalled Apache has an issue with mod_jk, is this going to be updated soon? Does any one know if CF2018 is working with Mojave?](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/10/2016-macos-10-14-mojave-preinstalled-apache-issue-mod_jk-going-updated-soon-one-know-cf2018-working-mojave/)

Comment: Looks like the issue lies with Mac OS X Mojave, and based on the bug thread, it [appears it may be resolved in Mac 10.14.4 Beta](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4203359).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem had to do with a conflict with Mac OS X and Coldfusion/Apache.  Because Mac OS X 10.14.4 fixed the "mod_jk" file that was conflicting with Apache, Coldfusion 2018 can now run on Mac OS X.

In order to solve the problem, I needed to:

1. upgrade Mac OS X to 10.14.4
2. stop all other servers
3. install Coldfusion 2018
4. set up Coldfusion Apache Connector
5. set up local virtual host

I confirmed that it worked on another computer, and have documented detailed instructions in this post: https://www.steckinsights.com/configuring-coldfusion-2018-with-apache-on-mac-os-x-mojave/

Fair warning: I think that the mod_jk issue in Mac OS 10.14.3 and prior was the issue, but there were so many different aspects I tested in the process, that there may be unique issues related to your particular computer's configuration.  I hope hope this helps anyone out there having issues.