# How to install Coldfusion on Mac OS X 10.15 Catalina using external virtual host

Tags: macos, apache, coldfusion

[I've been here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55174982/localhost-coldfusion-install-showing-cfquery-parameters-on-page-not-speaking-wi?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C61.3038) and even wrote an article on [how I was able to connect Coldfusion 2018 with Mac OS X Mojave](https://www.steckinsights.com/configuring-coldfusion-2018-with-apache-on-mac-os-x-mojave/), but since the upgrade to Mac OS X 10.15 Catalina, I haven't been able to get Coldfusion to work correctly on virtual hosts (ie. http://local.mylocalsite.com).

**Goal:** install Apache connector for Coldfusion so that I can run my dev site from within the /Sites folder like I would any other site.

**Problem:** Apache is working and I can access websites from the /Sites folder using the virtual host (ie. local.mydevsite.com), but although Coldfusion is running (I can access the Coldfusion Administrator), my computer does not seem to recognize that Coldfusion is supposed to run.  I don't know if this is Apache or Coldfusion's responsibility.

**What I've tried:** I've tried using the GUI connector, as well as trying to [confirm the settings via command line](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/web-server-management.html).  I have XAMPP installed, which I believe that DesktopServer (an application by ServerPress) is relying on, but that's probably not relevant; but what I'm getting at is that I believe XAMPP relies on Mac's default installation of Apache.

I've also tried to go into every file that is referenced in any instruction document to determine if there is anything out of place.  Part of my confusion is that there are many instances of some of these files and I'm not sure which one is active.  Here are some of the files I've looked into:

- /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
- /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
- /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf/mod_jk.so
- /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
- /private/etc/apache2/mod_jk.conf
- /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

From what I can tell, the main settings for Apache are stored in the /private/etc/apache2 folder, but I want the XAMPP version of https-vhosts.conf because that's where DesktopServer is pulling their virtual hosts from.  Regardless, I don't think it matters which vhosts file is being used because Coldfusion won't run on any of the local sites from my /Sites folder that are loading correctly when I visit local.anylocaldevsite.com.

Thoughts? This is either a really dumb question because no one else is asking it, or there aren't many Mac users who also use Coldfusion.  Would love assistance if anyone has a clue.  Thanks!

**Update:** This isn't an exact answer, but the recommendation to try CommandBox was a win.  I installed CommandBox and then ran the "ColdBox" application in the root of my project and the site opened up in my browser like a gem.  Wonderful.  Thank you!  I can call that the "answer" if no one objects, but I know that it's more of a workaround than an exact fix.

Comment: Is using Ortus Solutions Commandbox an option?

Comment: It's more like, "there aren't many users who also use ColdFusion" and of those, the number of Mac users is much, much smaller. I don't bother installing CF on Mac without ColdBox anymore. It's just not worth the time. You might try asking in https://cfml.slack.com/ where a good portion of the CF Community hangs out. The Ortus Solutions team would probably know better than most.

Comment: I've had XAMPP+Coldfusion coexisting before on Windows many versions of each ago. I know other people who use Macs. I know other people who use Coldfusion. I don't know of anyone personally who uses XAMPP on a Mac. I don't know of anyone personally who uses Coldfusion on a Mac. I would not be at all surprised if you were the first to attempt to use Mac OS Catalina + Coldfusion 2018 + XAMPP in the same installation. 

I do remember the XAMPP issue of multiple versions of conf files - my inelegant solution was to modify/remove each one and restart to see for certain which files were in use.

Comment: When you say _"haven't been able to get Coldfusion to work correctly"_ and _"my computer does not seem to recognize that Coldfusion is supposed to run"_ - what are the actual symptoms you're seeing? And were you installing a new CF update at the same time as the Mac OS upgrade? If you were updating both at the same time then you might be hitting issues with the CF update that are not specific to your environment, eg https://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2020/3/20/how_and_why_sites_may_break_after_Mar_2020_CF_updates

Comment: Thanks @JamesAMohler and Adrian J Moreno.  Maybe I'll need to give ColdBox/CommandBox a try.  I was being stubborn because I had made it work once and have that sneaky suspicion that if I just knew more then I could solve it.

Comment: @Sev-Roberts The best I can do to answer your question is explain that Coldfusion installed correctly and runs on port 8500.  I can get to the Coldfusion admin panel without a problem.  The more correct issue is that the "Coldfusion Connector for Mac OS X Catalina" does not appear to install correctly -- so I can't seem to make the site running in my "/Sites" folder run as an external web server with Coldfusion seeing and responding to the CF commands in the .cfm files on the site that runs in the "/Sites/mysite" folder.

Comment: So when you try to hit a .cfm in one of those sites from a browser, do you get a timeout, or an HTTP 404, 403, 503, or some other Apache error?

Comment: Thanks @SevRoberts.  I gave up on this and decided to use ColdBox/CommandBox instead.  Made life SO much easier.  Local site runs using that without a problem.  Not sure there is a simple way to get it running locally without that.